# How to add button on a cell and if some field is null not to add button in developer express grid

Tags: vb.net, delphi, devexpress

I have a grid with buttons on two columns but if a field is null I don't want that button to be visible. I am working in Delphi; I found solution in VB

```
Private Sub gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CustomRowCellEditEventArgs) Handles gridView1.CustomRowCellEdit
    If e.Column Is gridColumn1 Then
        Dim ri As RepositoryItemButtonEdit = TryCast(e.RepositoryItem.Clone(), RepositoryItemButtonEdit)
        ri.Assign(e.RepositoryItem)
        e.RepositoryItem = ri
        Dim buttonCount As Integer = CInt(Fix(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle,gridColumn2)))
        For i As Integer = 0 To buttonCount - 1
            TryCast(e.RepositoryItem, RepositoryItemButtonEdit).Buttons(i).Visible = True
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

But this event does not exist in Delphi. Which event should I use? And how to solve this problem if `tblMailJournalTask.FieldByName('anQId').Value = null`not to show button.

Comment: Is there `OnDrawColumnCell` event? If so, this is your event.

Comment: I don't get to the RepositoryItemButtonEdit and RepositoryItem how shoud I get to them? which uses item should I put?

Comment: You add these to a TcxEditRepository that you place on your form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set up a grid in which the `Properties` value of the 3rd column (called `cxGrid1DBTableView1Value`) is set to ButtonEdit.

Then, the code below causes the button not to be displayed in the cell if the data value in the cell is Null.

Obviously, if there is more than one button in the cell, you could iterate over them to set the Visible property of each of them, if you want all of them to be hidden when the data value is Null.

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1ValueGetPropertiesForEdit(Sender:
    TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; var AProperties:
    TcxCustomEditProperties);
var
  ADataRow : TcxGridDataRow;
  AValue : Variant;
begin
  if ARecord is TcxGridDataRow then begin
    ADataRow := TcxGridDataRow(ARecord);
    Assert(ADataRow.ValueCount > 0);  // this is for debugging/testing
    AValue := ADataRow.Values[2];  // the value in the third column
    if Assigned(AProperties.Buttons) then begin // this test is for debugging/testing  
      if VarIsNull(AValue) then
        AProperties.Buttons[0].Visible := False
      else
        AProperties.Buttons[0].Visible := True;
     end;
  end;
end;
```

**Update:** If you want to show yourself that clicking the button does something, do the following:

1. Select your grid column in the Object Inspector
2. Click on the `Events` tab
3. Scroll down to the `Properties` entry, and click it to expand it
4. Double-click in its `OnButtonClick` and add something like the following.

.

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1ValuePropertiesButtonClick(
  Sender: TObject; AButtonIndex: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(AButtonIndex));
end;
```

**Update2**

Here is the complete code & DFM of a project which behaves as I've described above.

Code:

```
unit CXSimpleLocalu;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  Variants, cxGraphics, cxControls, cxLookAndFeels, cxLookAndFeelPainters,
  cxStyles, dxSkinsCore, dxSkinBlack, dxSkinBlue, dxSkinBlueprint,
  dxSkinCaramel, dxSkinCoffee, dxSkinDarkRoom, dxSkinDarkSide,
  dxSkinDevExpressDarkStyle, dxSkinDevExpressStyle, dxSkinFoggy,
  dxSkinGlassOceans, dxSkinHighContrast, dxSkiniMaginary, dxSkinLilian,
  dxSkinLiquidSky, dxSkinLondonLiquidSky, dxSkinMcSkin, dxSkinMetropolis,
  dxSkinMetropolisDark, dxSkinMoneyTwins, dxSkinOffice2007Black,
  dxSkinOffice2007Blue, dxSkinOffice2007Green, dxSkinOffice2007Pink,
  dxSkinOffice2007Silver, dxSkinOffice2010Black, dxSkinOffice2010Blue,
  dxSkinOffice2010Silver, dxSkinOffice2013DarkGray,
  dxSkinOffice2013LightGray, dxSkinOffice2013White, dxSkinPumpkin,
  dxSkinSeven, dxSkinSevenClassic, dxSkinSharp, dxSkinSharpPlus,
  dxSkinSilver, dxSkinSpringTime, dxSkinStardust, dxSkinSummer2008,
  dxSkinTheAsphaltWorld, dxSkinsDefaultPainters, dxSkinValentine,
  dxSkinVS2010, dxSkinWhiteprint, dxSkinXmas2008Blue, dxSkinscxPCPainter,
  cxCustomData, cxFilter, cxData, cxDataStorage, cxEdit, cxNavigator, DB,
  cxDBData, cxButtonEdit, cxGridCustomTableView, cxGridTableView,
  cxGridDBTableView, cxGridLevel, cxClasses, cxGridCustomView, cxGrid,
  DBClient, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    CDS1ID: TAutoIncField;
    CDS1Name: TStringField;
    CDS1Value: TStringField;
    CDS1Selected: TBooleanField;
    cxGrid1DBTableView1: TcxGridDBTableView;
    cxGrid1Level1: TcxGridLevel;
    cxGrid1: TcxGrid;
    cxGrid1DBTableView1ID: TcxGridDBColumn;
    cxGrid1DBTableView1Name: TcxGridDBColumn;
    cxGrid1DBTableView1Value: TcxGridDBColumn;
    cxGrid1DBTableView1Selected: TcxGridDBColumn;
    procedure cxGrid1DBTableView1ValueGetPropertiesForEdit(Sender:
        TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; var AProperties:
        TcxCustomEditProperties);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure cxGrid1DBTableView1ValuePropertiesButtonClick(
      Sender: TObject; AButtonIndex: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1ValueGetPropertiesForEdit(Sender:
    TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; var AProperties:
    TcxCustomEditProperties);
var
  ADataRow : TcxGridDataRow;
  AValue : Variant;
begin
  if ARecord is TcxGridDataRow then begin
    ADataRow := TcxGridDataRow(ARecord);
    Assert(ADataRow.ValueCount > 0);
    AValue := ADataRow.Values[2];
    if Assigned(AProperties.Buttons) then begin
      if VarIsNull(AValue) then
        AProperties.Buttons[0].Visible := False
      else
        AProperties.Buttons[0].Visible := True;
     end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  CDS1.CreateDataSet;
  for i:= 0 to 5 do begin
    CDS1.Insert;
    CDS1.FieldByName('Name').AsString := Chr(i + Ord('a'));
    if Odd(i) then
      CDS1.FieldByName('Value').AsString := '#';
    CDS1.Post;
  end;
 // CDS1.MergeChangeLog;
end;

procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1ValuePropertiesButtonClick(
  Sender: TObject; AButtonIndex: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(AButtonIndex));
end;

end.
```

DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 348
  Top = 166
  AutoScroll = False
  Caption = 'MADefaultForm'
  ClientHeight = 314
  ClientWidth = 444
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  Scaled = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object cxGrid1: TcxGrid
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 444
    Height = 314
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 1
    object cxGrid1DBTableView1: TcxGridDBTableView
      Navigator.Buttons.CustomButtons = <>
      DataController.DataSource = DataSource1
      DataController.KeyFieldNames = 'ID'
      DataController.Summary.DefaultGroupSummaryItems = <>
      DataController.Summary.FooterSummaryItems = <>
      DataController.Summary.SummaryGroups = <>
      object cxGrid1DBTableView1ID: TcxGridDBColumn
        DataBinding.FieldName = 'ID'
      end
      object cxGrid1DBTableView1Name: TcxGridDBColumn
        DataBinding.FieldName = 'Name'
      end
      object cxGrid1DBTableView1Value: TcxGridDBColumn
        DataBinding.FieldName = 'Value'
        PropertiesClassName = 'TcxButtonEditProperties'
        Properties.Buttons = <
          item
            Default = True
            Kind = bkEllipsis
          end>
        Properties.OnButtonClick = cxGrid1DBTableView1ValuePropertiesButtonClick
        OnGetPropertiesForEdit = cxGrid1DBTableView1ValueGetPropertiesForEdit
      end
      object cxGrid1DBTableView1Selected: TcxGridDBColumn
        DataBinding.FieldName = 'Selected'
        PropertiesClassName = 'TcxButtonEditProperties'
        Properties.Buttons = <
          item
            Default = True
            Kind = bkEllipsis
          end>
      end
    end
    object cxGrid1Level1: TcxGridLevel
      GridView = cxGrid1DBTableView1
    end
  end
  object CDS1: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    Left = 24
    Top = 16
    object CDS1ID: TAutoIncField
      FieldName = 'ID'
    end
    object CDS1Name: TStringField
      FieldName = 'Name'
      Size = 8
    end
    object CDS1Value: TStringField
      FieldName = 'Value'
      Size = 32
    end
    object CDS1Selected: TBooleanField
      FieldName = 'Selected'
    end
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = CDS1
    Left = 64
    Top = 16
  end
end
```

Comment: @ververicka Note that the OnGetProperties is for loading the editor that is used to display the value, OnGetPropertiesForEdit is for loading the editor that is used to edit the value. So depending on what/when you want to change the editor you use either OnGetProperties or OnGetPropertiesForEdit. If you only use OnGetProperties the 'edit editor' will be the same as the 'display' one ([same applies to treelists](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q451850))

Comment: @JanDoggen:  Thanks.  The code I've included in the answer produces an AV in my minimalist testbed if executed in OnGetProperties for some reason.  The AV actually occurs *after* the OnGetProperties handler code has exited, in TDataLink.DataEvent in DB.Pas.

Comment: Sorry I am going to be a little pain here but I just don't like seeing `then begin` on the same line :) Another slight thing you could simplify is writing this instead of what you put: `AProperties.Buttons[0].Visible := VarIsNull(AValue);` and that way you can skip the whole `if` and `else` statement expression, I'm sure you know this already though :)

Comment: @Craig:  the `then begin` thing is a matter of taste, obviously.  The reason I do it is that in an editing window, there is only so much vertical space and putting `begin` on its own line pretty much guarantees that something more interesting is scrolled out of view.  As for the other point, sure but esp when I'm experimenting, like here, I prefer the long-winded way, because I can follow the execution flow by single-stepping the debugger.

Comment: @MartynA it is working but it is strange the button is shown and when I click it desipierd do you have any other idea? I don't want buttuns to be seen

Comment: @MartynA of course, you're not the only one who writes this way so I wasn't having a personal dig or anything. I just saw it and my eyes didn't like it :)

Comment: *when I click it desipierd*  Most likely because you haven't set up an event handler - see **update** in my answer. *I don't want buttuns to be seen* Err, I thought you wanted them to be visible if the cell value isn't null.

Comment: yes I want to be visible when the cell is not null but I don't want to be visible otherwise

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting confused.  The way the code in the answer works is that when the cell is not focused, the button is **not** displayed (which is standard behaviour), and when the cell **is** focused, the button is displayed **only** if the cell value is not null.  That's what I understood you are asking for; if it isn't, please explain **exactly** what you do want.

Comment: It is ok I had onAfterScroll method that initialized the buttons. Now it is ok

Comment: Ok, well I've updated my answer to include a stand-alone project in which the button in the Value column behaves as I described.